# May I see who is not following me on Google+?

Tags: google-plus

I have people following me that I follow, people who follow me who I do not and people who I follow but who do not follow me.  Is there a way to see those three lists?

Comment: Knowing that is against the whole concept of Google+.

Answer (score 3):

The people you follow are in [your Circles](https://plus.google.com/circles).

The people who are following you but you are not following them are in the [Added you](https://plus.google.com/circles/addedyou) area. Select the "Not yet in circles" option.

It's not all that easy to see the people you are following that aren't following you (except for those who are not using Google+).

---

There are, however, some Chrome extensions that can help you find those asymmetrical relationships. ([How-to article](http://googleplusblog.co.uk/2011/11/how-to-find-and-remove-unfollowers-google-plus/) / [Circloscope](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/circloscope-free-uncircle/fnckobddbbbgfabnhogmncmghngohflh) extension)

Answer (score -1):

Well, it may be hard to find it using mobile, but your followers are in 'added you to their circles.' 
Google+ is still updating to make it easier and to let you know how you are not following but they are